# Using diff-highlight with Git GUI

Tags: git

Is there a way to use [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) with [git gui](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui)?

The extra highlighted info is invaluable when comparing lines that only changed a bit, and while using diff-highlight from the terminal (described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ydluzg/better-git-diff)) is great, when I'm trying to make sense of large changes, I really like using the gui.

It doesn't look like there's much of a way.
I tried editing the Additional diff parameters in the gui and hacking on something like `| diff-highlight`, but that was no good.

Also worth noting: using `--color-words` is not a good workaround.
First, [it breaks git gui](http://neurotap.blogspot.com/2012/04/character-level-diff-in-git-gui.html). Second, the diff output isn't nearly as easy to read as that of a normal diff processed through diff-highlight.

Comment: I think this belongs on superuser.SE rather than SO. Please consider posting it there.

Comment: Okay, did that, thanks. Post is [here](http://superuser.com/questions/933872/using-diff-highlight-with-git-gui). Should I remove this one?